# Lua redirect stdout to console window

Tags: lua, popen

I'm trying to write a lua script that has need of displaying messages to the user, which of course the host application provides only limited support for.

So I'd like to open a console window and redirect print() to it. I'd expect something like this to work:

```
io.stdout = io.popen('find /v ""', "w")
print("It works!")
```

but the console window just closes immediately, rather than waiting for input from the pipe.

Using lua 5.1 on Windows 7

Edit: I've noticed that the `find` command terminates when the pipe is closed. Could it be that it's failing to read from the pipe, or the pipe is closing prematurely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, to open a console for output on Windows, this works:

```
local out = io.popen('find /v "" > con', "w")
function print(s)
  out:write(s.."\r\n") --\r because windows
  out:flush()
end
print("It really works this time!")
```

The find command seemed to be terminating early because it didn't have a specified `stdout`; providing the `> con` at the end tells it to set `stdout` to the console, and keeps the console open.

Comment: +1 for posting solution and glad you figured it out!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me on Windows 10 with luaJIT 2.0. No console appears.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write data to the pipe:

```
pipe = io.popen('find /v ""', "w")
pipe:write("It works!")
```

There is no indication from the docs that `io.stdout` can be reset to point to some other file handle. In fact there is indication from some posts that `print` calls `fputs` directly, not via `io.stdout`. You are probably better off pointing `print` to the pipe's writer method

```
old_print = print
print = function(...) pipe:write(...) end
```

Then any call to `print` after the above is executed will go to the pipe. Ideally you should restore `print` to what it was, once the script ends:

```
print = old_print
```

Comment: That makes sense, it could have been the pipe being garbage collected if `io.stdout` isn't writable. However, the console window still closes immediately. I thought it might be that `find` is an internal command, so I tried `io.popen('cmd /d /c find /v ""', "w")`, but that was no different. Running `echo hello | cmd /d /c find /v ""` from a command prompt works fine, so it shouldn't be the pipe not taking.

Comment: why are you expecting the console to stay open after the `pipe:write`?

Comment: Because my script continues running and I need to write multiple times, and the text I write to the pipe never shows up and is unreadable if the console closes immediately. Maybe I should clarify a bit: my script is an install script that takes a few minutes, and, given that the host program freezes when my script is running, I need output of some sort to reassure the user that everything is running as it should.

Comment: so you mean that the find command takes a long time and you want to let the user know regular intervals that find is still operating?

Comment: Nonono, I'm trying to use `find` to write the output my script (as I output it, as it consists of debugging messages and status updates) to a console window. I don't have a console (or anything else, for that matter) to provide visible output to the user, so I'm trying to spawn one I can output to using `io.popen`, `find` seemed like a good fit, as: 1: it accepts pipe input 2: outputs to a console window 3: can be set to output everything I send it exactly as I send it.

Comment: Sorry ive been using this stuff for years but i don't get what you are trying to do. If you are wanting to capture the output of "find", why are you opening a write pipe to it, what you need is a read pipe.

Comment: No, a write pipe is what I needed, what I hadn't realized is that I needed to explicitly direct `find`'s output to the console via `> con`. Thanks for trying to help though, I'm sorry I couldn't explain what I needed clearly enough.